# angular select reactive form dropdown problem

Tags: javascript, angular, forms

I have a problem with a select dropdown in angular. I use reactive form but the dropdown is not working and I don't know why and how to fix it. Can someone please help me? thank you.

TS code

```
form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
genderList = [{ type: 'Female' }, { type: 'Male' }];

selectedObject: any = this.genderList[0];

consoleLog(state: any) {
    console.log(state);
  }
```

HTML

```
<select
        [formControlName]="selectedObject"
        class="form-control"
        (change)="consoleLog(selectedObject)"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedObject"
      >
        <option *ngFor="let g of genderList" [ngValue]="g">
          {{ g.type }}
        </option>
      </select>
```

In the UI the code its not working properly at dropdown and i get this:

```
core.js:6479 ERROR Error: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup
       directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).

      Example:

      
    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>
```

Any idea how to fix it in order to be able to select what gender the person is? Thanks a lot for your time.

Regards

Comment: The error is quite clear. Do you have the select control in a div or form with a `formGroup`  value set? And why are you using `ngModel` when you are using Reactive Forms? That will not work.

Comment: Hi R. Richards, thanks for your response. Yes i have a form  <form [formGroup]="form"></form> like this and I read that ngModel its not working but I can't make it work, I am not sure how to bind form ControlName in order to make the code work. Do you any advice or idea? Thank you so much

Comment: You should read this: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Answer (score 0):

As Richards mentioned, you can't use both reactive and template driven(ngModel) approach at the same time, judging by the title of your question I guess you want to use reactive approach so remove ngModel and fix formControlName, it accepts string but you're binding it with an object, it should be like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="myGroup">
    <select formControlName="gender"> other stuff... </select>
</form>
```

where gender is just a plain string not a property or you could also do it like this:

```
<select [formControlName]="'gender'">
```